# Speed up Z3 to CNF conversion

Tags: z3, z3py

I have predicate that operates with 32bit numbers and I want to convert it to CNF.

I'm using Z3py for that the following way:

```
value = compute_value(BitVec("x", 32))
threshold = compute_threshold(BitVec("y", 32))
is_valid = value < threshold

g = Goal()
g.add(is_valid)
t = Then('simplify', 'bit-blast', 'tseitin-cnf')
result = t(g)
print(result)
```

Listings of `compute_value` and `compute_threshold` are few hundreds lines of code. I don't think it's reasonable to show them. Output of both is also 32bit BitVec.

I also tried to use `tseitin-cnf-core` and `elim-and` tactics, but I always have to break computation because Z3 consumes all my RAM.

That seems strange. As far as I know tseitin conversion requires only O(n) time and space. I suspect Z3 performs unnecessary simplifications of formula which requires so many resources.

What tactics should I use to speed up? Or maybe you know tool better than Z3 to convert predicate with arithmetic expressions to CNF?

Comment: Once you bit-blast, the expressions might become really large, especially if you have complicated operations like multiplication/division/modulus etc. Hard to opine without knowing exactly what's going on in `compute_threshold`. Did you try without running `simplify`? It'd be good to isolate the issue down to a single-tactic, and make it reproducible by others.

Comment: There are no multiplications and divisions, but a lot of addition and bit operations: and, or, xor and shifts. I tried to run without simplify, but Z returns error "operator bvsub is not supported, you must simplify the goal before applying bit-blasting"

Comment: I'd look at the output of the bit-blast; how big is it, compared to your original?

Comment: "simplify" and "bit-blast" outruns my RAM too. But I can compute "simplify" only, print shows 200 first lines of result. First lines looks like 
`[[Not(13960450711994363030255127593764523087979983609872252928 <=
      Concat(153 +
             228*Extract(31, 24, nonce) +
             204*
             Concat(Extract(13,`
I don't know to measure it's size correctly

Comment: yeah; looks like your problem is with bit-blast, not tseitin. Bit-blasting big formulas can cause lots of trouble as well. Looks like your problem is just too big for z3 or your machine is too impoverished.